# Question concerning the correctness of this version of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In lecture we learned about Fatou's Lemma stated as follows:

Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(f_k : X \to [0,\infty])$ measurable and $f: X \to [0, \infty] $ a function such that:
$ f = \liminf_{k \to \infty} f_k $ almost everywhere
Then $f$ is measurable and
$ \int_X f  d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_X f_k  d\mu. $

I am thinking that the statement written in this way is not correct. Since f need not be measurable. We can only guarantee this in complete measure spaces. Is there something I am missing or do we need to change the statement.

Comment: $\int f_k d\mu$ has no meaning without assumption of measurability. If $f_k$ is measurable for each $k$ then $f$ is measurable too and the conclusion holds; we just have to go to the completion.

Comment: I forgot the $f_k$ are supposed to be measurable

Comment: Completion always exists and it is understood that $\int f d\mu$ is defined by going to the completion.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks!

Comment: What does the completion of $X$ have to do with anything here?

Comment: @Michael The completion of the measure space. We need to be sure that a function that equals a measurable function outside a null set is actually measurable itself.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : I see, this says that $f$ is the $\liminf$ "almost everywhere." There would be no need for completion if we just define $f=\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty} f_k$.

Comment: Exactly, that was my issue

Comment: @Ramiro I do not see why the first definition does not lead to problems. It could still be true for all X apart from a nonmeasurable set which is a subset of a set of measure $0$.

Comment: @Ramiro I understand the set $N$ has to be measurable. Would you be so kind and share a prove to why this definition implies that the other function is again measurable